# How to get the value of input in Material-UI

Tags: jquery, reactjs, material-ui

in I am using Material-UI in React.

```
render(){return (
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" 
    onChange={this.handleMasterVolume} class="master-gain form-control" id="master-gain"/>);
}
handleMasterVolume(){
    $(this).val();// if jquery I can get the value here.
    console.log(value);
}
```

I want to get the input value in the passed function.

If jquery I can use `$(this)` but in Material-UI????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you are not using Material UI. The `input` you are using is a html tag. If you want to use Material UI use [TextField](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#text-field) component with  `type="number"`

This

```
$(this).val();// if jquery I can get the value here.
```

will not work in React. Try something like below

```
handleMasterVolume(e) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: mmm, maybe I am also the newbee to React. so confused. thank you very much for clear explanation

Comment: @whitebear This React page will help you to work with with form elements in React JS - https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: To help ease your confusing I'll try to  build on his answer. In the jquery solution $(this) is binding the the onChange event. In the react answer the (e) parameter is the event. You can see what information the react event contains by simply console logging it. Specifically e.target is the element in the virtual dom and e.target.value is the value attribute on the html element.

Comment: Thank you @kiranvj and  @Nicholas_Jones. I need to get used to `e` parameter.

Comment: @whitebear `e` is nothing but the event emitted when you do an action like  click or keypress.  `e` is just a short form for event, you can use any variable name for this. This is not new in ReactJS, plain JavaScript also work in the same way. The first parameter of `onClick` is an event which has all the details of event, the element in with event has initiated etc. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)